# Bubble sort and file r/w task

Tags: python, bubble-sort

i am trying to do a bubble sort challenge on python, it involves both the sort and file reading. it is a high scores board for a game, the scores are kept in a txt file, the program needs to do these things:
enter names and scores (3 long each)
sort names and scores 
store the list, so i can open it after closing it and edit it
delete a name and score
replace a score to a name

i am doing it bit by bit, like a story. para by para each is a para.
i am a bit stuck on the last 2 points. i could do with some help for it. 
i am at gcse level, (ocr)

this is my sort program

```
def BubbleSort2(lst):
     lst = list(lst)
     swapped = True
     while swapped:
         swapped = False
         for i in range(len(lst)-1):
             if lst[i] < lst[i+1]:
                 lst[i], lst[i+1] = lst[i+1], lst[i]
                 swapped = True
     return lst
```

Comment: "He who "gcse level, (ocr)" rings any bells to, let him first cast a stone at her."

Comment: Namely, what specifically are the things you're stuck at?

Answer (score 0):

change if condition to `if lst[i] > lst[i+1]:` in your code. In bubble sorting, need to check `i`th element with `i+1` element  and if `i` element is greater then `i+1` element then exchange element.

code:

```
def bubbleSort(input, n):
    """
        Bubble Sort.
        Input: Input List and Number of elemnt in list
        Output: Sorted List
    """
    i = 1
    while i<n:  # Run n-1 times
        j = 0
        tmp = n-i
        while j<tmp:                        
            if input[j]>input[j+1]:  # Exchange values
                tmp1 = input[j]
                input[j] = input[j+1]
                input[j+1] = tmp1
            j += 1
        print "i=%d input:-%s"%(i, input)
        i += 1

    return list(input)

input = [6,5,4,3,2,1]
no = len(input)

print "\n", bubbleSort(input, no)
```

output:

```
$ python test.py 

i=1 input:-[5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 6]
i=2 input:-[4, 3, 2, 1, 5, 6]
i=3 input:-[3, 2, 1, 4, 5, 6]
i=4 input:-[2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6]
i=5 input:-[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```